# Enable crossdomain call on a java servlet for Silverlight application

Tags: java, silverlight, jetty, odata, odata4j

I have a java servlet with the **OData4j** library and I want to configure it so I can make HTTP POST request from a Silverlight application.

My web.xml file looks like this:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>OData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
     <param-value>org.odata4j.producer.resources.ODataResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>OData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myService/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I've tried adding this to my web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>CrossDomain</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
     <param-value>org.odata4j.producer.resources.CrossDomainResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CrossDomain</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried adding the "crossdomain.xml" and "clientaccesspolicy.xml" files to my resources directory but that also doesn't work. I still get a SecurityException when sending a HTTP POST request with my Silverlight application.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Is the security exception the indication that it "doesn't work" ? or is something else happen. What logs do you get?

Comment: Yeah, I meant a the same security exception. I finally found what was wrong; see the answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that instantiating CrossDomainResourceConfig does enable the "crossdomain.xml" and "clientaccesspolicy.xml" files. The thing is that they are available at the URL: `/myService/crossdomain.xml` and `/myService/clientaccesspolicy.xml`.

However, the Silverlight runtime looks for those files at the server root (eg: `/clientaccesspolicy.xml`)

By adding both of those files manually in the server root, it fixed the problem.